# jQuery noConflict on Wordpress Development

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently developing a wordpress plugin which using wp_enqueue_script function to include a js file. In order to prevent conflict of symbol '$', I wrapped the whole js script with code below.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
    $(function() {
        // any jquery event
    });
})(jQuery);
```

My question is, Im going to include multiple js file, how should I handle the the 'noconflict'? Should I duplicate the code above and insert into every single js file? Any other efficient way?

Is it possible to do something like:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'begin_isolation_script', 'begin_isolation.js' );            
wp_enqueue_script( 'test-script-1', 'test1.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'test-script-2', 'test2.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'test-script-3', 'test3.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'end_isolation_script', 'end_isolation.js' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) at all unless you are loading another library into the `$` namespace. In your wrapper code you refer to jQuery externally as `jQuery` which shouldn't cause any conflicts.

If you do want to call it, you would only need it on your first JavaScript file. The purpose of `noConflict()` is to provide compatibility with other libraries that use `$`, WordPress doesn't have anything that would cause a conflict by default.